# VBA Excel — Select Range from String

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select all rows smaller than 16 points in order to manually delete them. Programatically deleting them rescales images on the spreadsheet and breaks it (ChemBio generated chemical structures).

My code works up until it makes the selection:

```
Sub FindAndRemoveSmallRows()
Dim a As Range, b As Range, c As String
Set a = Selection
For Each b In a.Rows
    If b.Height < 16 Then
        c = c & b.Row & ":" & b.Row & ","
    End If
Next
If Right$(c, 1) = "," Then c = Left$(c, Len(c) - 1)
Range(c).Select
End Sub
```

How can I pass the string (which outputs, e.g., `"67:67,513:513,534:534"`) to `Range` in order to select the rows?

Comment: As I see it won't work only when all rows in `Selection` has height `>= 16` and since `c` is empty `Range(c).Select` throws an error. Can you add `MsgBox c` just before `Range(c).Select`. What message would you get?

Comment: I used `ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = c` instead; prints `904:904,928:928,968:968,969:969,992:992,1035:1035`.

Comment: What happend when code tries to evaluate `Range(c).Select`? Did you get any error? If yes, what is the error message?

Comment: It prints, `Run-time error '1004':` `Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`.

Comment: It looks like some sort of type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
Sub FindAndRemoveSmallRows()
Dim b As Range, c As Range
if typename(selection)<>"Range" then exit sub
For Each b In Selection.Rows
    If b.Height < 16 Then
        if c is nothing then 
            set c = b
        else
            set c = application.union(c, b)
        end if
    End If
Next
if not c is nothing then c.entirerow.Select
End Sub
```